# Whenever gem controller method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I'm trying to create a cron job that runs a controller method with the whenever gem but i'm having trouble.

**config\schedule.rb**

```
every 1.minutes do
  runner "Reset.reset"
end
```

**lib\reset.rb**

```
class Reset
  def reset
    logger.debug("This is the cron job")
  end
end
```

I also ran the whenever --update-crontab to update the cron job.

Why isn't the logger message showing up in the log?

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `Reset.reset` trys to call the reset method on the Reset class. That is, `Reset.reset` trys to call a *class method*.

Your reset method is an instance method. To define a `Reset.reset` class method, use:

```
class Reset
  def self.reset
    logger.debug("This is the cron job")
  end
end
```

Also, you'll need to make sure that you have a `self.logger` class method as well, or that code will just die.

Lastly, for your own edification: `Reset` as you have it written isn't a controller. It's just a plain old ruby object.

Comment: Uh also, and I can't be positive just from the question, but are you using Windows? I'm assuming you are the backslashes in the file path... Whenever works with `cron`, which is a *nix utility. It probably just won't work on windows.